# Average scroll rate in Google Studio

Tags: google-analytics, looker-studio

I want to calculate and display the average scroll depth in Data Studio from analytics.

I’m looking to get an average scroll depth in Studio. I’ve got the 10%,25%, etc scroll depth data coming in, but I now need to be able to calculate the average scroll % from this data.

To calculate the average scroll depth:

multiply the scrolled threshold by the number of events (10x500) + (20x400) + (30x475) +(40x300) + (50x200) + (60x100) +(70x75) +(80x60) + (90x20) + (100x10)

Then, take that total divided by the total number of events. 500 + 400 + 475... etc

Because I can’t reference cells in Studio I can’t get it to work. I’ve also tried Google Sheets, which does work to do the calculation, but then I can’t use Data Studios filter to provide a specific page path?

I'm thinking that perhaps the calculation will need to be done at data source, but I am not sure how to reference a 'cell'?

Comment: How are you capturing the scroll depth?

Comment: Using Google tag managers built in scroll depth analytics: https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/scroll-depth-trigger-google-tag-manager/

Comment: See my reply here on this duplicate thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62523902/8378148

Answer (score 0):

Data Studio doesn't work based on a concept of "cells", it works based on a concept of "[fields](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9188170)"—which are basically properties of the data source. Similarly, you don't have "formulas" per se, but rather "[calculated fields](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6299685)".  These fields can be created either at the chart-level (single-use, but doesn't require permissions to modify the data source) or in the data source (reusable across many charts, requires permissions to modify the data source). Most fields also have an aggregation type, which tells the report how to aggregate it in charts by default (e.g. Sum or Average).

When you either edit your data source and hit "Add Field" or the option with the same name under the "Add metric" or "Add dimension" menus on a chart, you'll be presented with a box to input the formula. To access a field, just type its name (of if you're in the data source, select it from the list on the left). The editor will also typically give you an auto-complete list below your cursor based on what you're typing. Once your entry matches a field, it will get a highlight box around it (the color is based on the type; green = dimension/string,blue = metric/number). The functions available are sort of a mash-up of something between what you'd expect in Google Sheets and in a SQL query, but with more constraints on when you're allowed to use certain functions.

The [documentation for calculated fields](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6299685) is pretty simple, so I'd recommend starting there before you try to do too much heavy-lifting in Data Studio. Because of constraints in Data Studio's data model, you'll often find that you need to create separate calculated fields for different parts of the formula, and then combine them in a new calculated field. I'll warn you that the error messages in the field editor aren't super helpful sometimes, so you may need to re-read the documentation for the functions and field types you're working with to ensure you get a valid result.

If you're running into problems, including the field names and values that you need in your calculation may help, including the source of the data (are these GA events?). The more details you give, including what you've already tried, the more helpful we can be. Also, make sure to read the docs first to make sure you have a good handle on the product you're using and the terminology the community is most likely to understand.